# Input dimension of cv2.perspectiveTransform

Tags: python, opencv, transform

The following code was a simple example for OpenCV perspectiveTransform function.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
src = np.array(((25, 25), (200, 20), (35, 210), (215, 200)), dtype=np.float32)
dest = np.array(((-50, -50), (50, -50), (-50, 50), (50, 50)), dtype=np.float32)
mtx = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dest)


original = np.array([((42, 42), (30, 100), (150, 75),(100, 150))], dtype=np.float32)
converted = cv2.perspectiveTransform(original, mtx)

print converted
```

It works well, but why do I need an additional dimension in the argument 'original' in `cv2.perspectiveTransform(original, mtx)` to make it work?

> original.shape => (1,4,2)
>   mtx.shape => (3,3)
>   src.shape => (4,2)

Answer (score 0):

**orignal** is the source image on which the prespective transform will be applied. [Opencv Docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20perspectiveTransform(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20m))

Comment: I don't think that's correct - OP is asking about cv2.perspectiveTransform which transforms (x, y) points. Image transformation is done with cv2.warpPerspective.